# MATLAB num2str format

Tags: matlab

I'm storing variable values in MATLAB and putting one of the variable values as part of the file name . e.g. `"Error=1e-003.mat"`, however different version of MATLAB gives me different format when I'm converting numbers to string using `num2str` command. The number `1e-3`, MATLAB2011 gives me `1e-003` and MATLAB2012 gives me `1e-03`.

This runs into trouble when I try to load a batch of files with a mix of those two format. Does anyone know a way to add a zero or delete a zero for the exponent so the names are consistent? Or any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you certain it's caused by the difference in Matlab versions? According to [this website](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) (near the bottom), it's a PC/Unix thing.

Comment: I won't be 100% sure that the problem is caused by different versions of MATLAB. But the 2 PCs that produce different results are both running Windows 7 and MATLAB 64bit. The only difference that might cause this problem (that I can think of) is the different versions of MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly robust way to do it:

```
A = num2str(YOUR_NUMBER, '%0.0e');

if A(end-2)=='-' || A(end-2)=='+'
    A = [A(1:end-2) '0' A(end-1:end)]; end
```

In words: convert the number, and check if the second-to-last character is either a `'+'` or a `'-'`. If this is so, add a `'0'`.

Comment: That's an excellent idea. Works very well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Specify a "Format string as the second argument like this:

```
>> disp(num2str(2920230,'%0.10e'))
2.9202300000e+006
```

here `%0.10e` means display at least 0 digits before decimal and exactly 10 digits after it in exponent form.

Comment: The problem isn't the number of zeros in the ground number, but in the exponent. Changing the num2str format doesn't change e+006 to e+06.